# addSubview: method horribly slow

Tags: objective-c, iphone, addsubview

I am trying to initialize a `ViewController` from another. Here is the code written in my first `ViewController`:

## MediasViewController.h

```
#import "MediasVideosViewController.h"

@interface MediasViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
{
    NSArray*                    videosList; 
    MediasVideosViewController  *mediasVideosViewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray*  videosList;
@property (nonatomic, retain) MediasVideosViewController*   mediasVideosViewController;
```

### **MediasViewController.m :**

```
if (self.mediasVideosViewController == nil)
{
    MediasVideosViewController* mediasVideos = [[MediasVideosViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MediasVideosView" bundle:nil];
    self.mediasVideosViewController = mediasVideos;
    self.mediasVideosViewController.videosList = self.videosList;
    [mediasVideos release];
}

NSDate *start = [NSDate date];
[mediasVideosViewController.view addSubview:nil];
NSLog(@"adding nil to mediasVideosViewController.view took %f seconds", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:start]);
```

### **Console result :**

> adding nil to
>   mediasVideosViewController.view took
>   4.261444 seconds

Seriously? More than 4s to add nil to `mediasVideosController` ? It's swings between 1s and 5s.

But if I remove this line :

```
self.mediasVideosViewController.videosList = self.videosList;
```

from MediasViewController.m, I get a really shorter loading time, like :

> adding nil to
>   mediasVideosViewController.view took
>   0.007613 seconds

It drives me crazy...

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call mediasVideosViewController.view, you are basically calling loadView for the first time.  You aren't just adding a subview, you are creating the entire view with that call.

Presumably, when you set the list of videos you are giving your loadView method a lot more work to do.  This will result in the behavior you see.

In a nutshell, check out your loadView method for clues.

EDIT:  I noticed you were loading the view controller from a NIB file, in that case you want to check viewDidLoad.

Comment: I just noticed you are creating this view controller from a nib file, in that case check viewDidLoad.

Comment: could you edit your answer to reflect NIB file loading so we can vote? thanks.

Comment: I was downloading too many images in my mediasVideosViewController. My viewDidLoad was too heavy to load. Thanks ! And yes, it would be nice to edit your answer ;)